# Exclude some IPs from a subnet in squid

Tags: squid, access-control-list

I have squid configuration to allow access to the proxy from a particular network `localnet`. I'm blocking access to media to all users except some IPs within the subnet. Here is the relevant part from the /etc/squid/squid.conf :

```
acl admins src 192.168.10.29 192.168.10.17
acl localnet src 192.168.10.0/24
http_access allow admins
http_access deny mediaprr localnet
http_reply_access deny media localnet
http_access allow localnet
```

where `media` and `mediaprr` are the ACLs blocking streaming.
When running this configuration, media is still blocked for `admins` group. I tried identifying `localnet` by IPs (just for testing):

```
acl localnet src 192.168.10.90 192.168.10.91
```

and then the media remained blocked for `localnet` but not for `admins`; and that led me to the conclusion that the problem was that `admins` resigns within the subnet of `localnet`. Is that assumption correct? And what can I do to exclude `admins` from the `localnet` subnet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea came to my mind right after posting the question:

```
acl admins src 192.168.10.29 192.168.10.17
acl localnet src 192.168.10.0/24
http_access allow mediaprr admins
http_reply_access allow media admins
http_access deny mediaprr localnet
http_reply_access deny media localnet
http_access allow localnet
```

should allow `admins` to access media right before denying `localnet` use to media. Tested and worked...